# For any $n>1$ , $ Aut(\mathbb Z^n) \cong GL(n , \mathbb Z)$ ? And for any $m,n >1$ , $Aut(\mathbb Z_m ^n) \cong GL(n , \mathbb Z_m)$ ?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

Is it true that for any $n>1$ , $ Aut(\mathbb Z^n) \cong GL(n , \mathbb Z)$ ?

And is it true that for any $m,n >1$ , $Aut(\mathbb Z_m ^n) \cong GL(n , \mathbb Z_m)$ ?

( One problem I'm having with showing these automorphisms is the part that I cannot show that for any automorphism $f$ on $\mathbb Z^n$ , or $\mathbb Z_m^n$ , the matrix $\Big [ f(e_1) \space f(e_2) \space ... \space f(e_n)\Big]$ is invertible , where $e_i$ is the ordered pair , written in column form , whoose $i$-th position is $1$ and all other position is $0$ )

Comment: Well if $f$ is an automorphism it has an inverse... What do you get when you multiply this matrix with the corresponding matrix of the inverse of $f$?

Comment: The answer is yes, and you can replace ${\mathbb Z}$ by any commutative ring.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Any commutative ring ?? I think that integers plays a crucial role , otherwise how do you represent every group automorphism as a matrix ?

Comment: Prove that that matrix is invertible by constructing its inverse.  It is just the matrix associated to the inverse of the automorphisme $f$.  Another thing,   if you work in an arbitrary commutaive (unital) ring $R$, there is no problem in representing the automorphisms as matrices, the entries of your matrices  are elements of $R$ instead of beaing integers.